# Change Windows Explorer taskbar button target without multiple processes

Tags: windows-7, windows, taskbar

By default the Windows Explorer link pinned to the Windows 7 taskbar takes you to Libraries. Is it possible to alter this target to my user folder without having it launch in a separate process?

What I mean by this is that I know you can alter the target to `%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe %userprofile%` or one of the many variations; and there are a whole bunch of questions on this site explaining just that. However when you click it it opens as a separate item on the taskbar. On my previous computer I used a different method to alter the target directory that didn't suffer this problem, can't remember how I did it though.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the shortcut's target to: `%windir%\explorer.exe shell:Profile`

Source, with a long list of other supported targets:
[How to Change the Windows 7 Pinned Windows Explorer Taskbar Icon Open To Target](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/2863-windows-explorer-taskbar-icon-change-open-target.html)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this? [How to Change the Windows 7 Pinned Windows Explorer Taskbar Icon Open To Target](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/2863-windows-explorer-taskbar-icon-change-open-target.html)